# How to use a bound variable in <a>'s href?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, href

I need to create a dynamic link which makes use of a bound variable. The "dynamism" of the link is done though a modification of the `href` field with a bound variable `ip`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    ip: "10.1.1.1"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a href="http://example.com/{{ip}}">{{ip}}</a>
</div>
```

This does not work because `{{ip}}` is not interpolated and I get a warning

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use `v-bind` or the
>   colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`,
>   use `<div :id="val">`.

Switching `href=` into `:href=` breaks the template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    ip: "10.1.1.1"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a :href="http://example.com/ip">{{ip}}</a>
</div>
```

**How can I use bound values in href?**

EDIT: I cannot use a computed value (which would have been the first idea) because I am in a Buefy table and uses the data current to the row i am in (see https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/vrOgOX?editors=1010 for an example, the `props.row` elements properties are my `ip`)

Comment: You could use a computed?

Comment: IIRC, `<a :href="'http://example.com/' + ip">{{ip}}</a>` would work.

Comment: @ceejayoz: yes it does, thank you. It is perfect because I cannot use a computed value (at least I think so) because I am in a Bueify table (https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/vrOgOX?editors=1010). Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @thanksd: oh yes, an exact duplicate - I mark it as such. Thanks. (EDIT: ... but it is not immediately marked as a dupe even though me as the author says so ...)

Answer (score 0):

you could use it with a computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    ip: "10.1.1.1"
  },
  computed: {
    ipUrl: function() {
      return `http://example.com/${this.ip}`;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a :href="ipUrl">{{ip}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are using an arrow function like that, `getIpUrl` is going to return `http://example.com/undefined`, because you're referencing the wrong `this`.

Comment: you are right, you have to do it with a normal function. Corrected it in the answer.

Comment: If that's a _property_ it should be named `ipUrl`. `getIpUrl` is a name for a _method_, and looks quite unreadable in the template, where you use it without call syntax.

Comment: your are right @Frax Let me quickly update my snippet for others. I had a method in place before here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a JS Expression inside `:href`, like

```
<a :href="'http://example.com/' + ip">IP</a>
```

Note the single quotes (devoting string) inside the double quotes (enclosing attribute value/definition).

Comment: I personally would prefer a computed property instead of a expression in the html attributes so leave the "logic" to the script and the display to the html.

Comment: That's the matter of taste of course, but I'd say that calling simple concatenation a "logic" is quite a stretch. Even more so if you write it with new string literal notation. Unless the url is needed in multiple places (and so computed property de-duplicates the code), I'd say writing expression inline is better for sheer brevity and simplicity.

Comment: Depends completely on the context in my eyes. But I agree, its a matter of taste. Thats why I said, I prefer it as computed. I like to take away all interpolations or expressions from the html and leave it up to the js part, but just my own way of working it out :)